# Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS securely

Tags: php, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to use Google Cloud Services in a secure way. I am currently providing my credentials via putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=*path to JSON file*'); See  https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

I am wanting to test publicly by putting my code on a shared host / virtual Linux server. However, if I set permissions of the JSON file to be secure they can't be accessed. If I make the public, the JSON file I need to include has a private key in plain text.

I've done an hours worth of searching, but can't find how I am supposed to provide credentials securely.

- Am I supposed to have the file on my server in a secure location?
- Is there an alternative for production websites to passing a public URL in to putenv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple answer to your question.

**Part 1 - Your host is not on Google Cloud**

**Is your host secure?** If yes, then it is OK to place the service account JSON key in a directory that is not accessible from your public-facing applications. Here I mean do not place the file in the same directory as your webserver. Use a location such as `/config` and then tighten the security on that directory so that only authorized users and your application can read the file.

Once you have determined a secure file location for your credentials file, specify that service account directly in your code. Do not use environment variables or command-line switches. Do not use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Some comments are to use KMS. Using KMS is a good idea, but you have a chicken-or-the-egg situation. You need credentials to use KMS decrypt. If a bad-actor can access your encrypted credentials they can also access your source code, or reverse-engineer the application, to see the decryption method and the service account used for decryption.

Note: Specifying a static location for credential files is not a best-practice for DevOps. Your question is about security and not CI/CD. You are using a shared server, which can mean many things and DevOps is probably not integrated into your deployments or system design.

**If your host is not secure**, then you have no viable options. Nothing that you can do can prevent a "skilled" engineer from reversing your method of "obscuration".

**Part 2 - Your host is on Google Cloud (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, App Engine, etc)**

*Note: The techniques below are in beta. This is the future for Google Cloud Authorization which is Identity Bases Access Control to compliment Role Based Access Control and in some cases replace it.*

You can assign the host a service account that has zero permissions. Note the word "assign" and not "create". No files are involved. Then you can use Identity Based access control (the IAM member account ID of the service account) to access resources. I wrote two articles on this for Google Cloud Run which applies to other Google services (Compute Engine, Cloud Functions, KMS, Cloud Storage, Cloud Scheduler, etc):

- [Google Cloud Run – Identity](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/)
- [Google Cloud – Go – Identity Based Access Control](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-go-identity-based-access-control/)

Comment: your site's down :s

Comment: @Ben - I just checked and it is up. Can you double-check for me?

Comment: @Ben - Stackdriver shows the site has been rebooted several times starting around 11 PM PST with the site down for about 6 minutes each time. Probably Google maintenance (I hope).

Comment: can confirm, it is up

Comment: Do your blog runs on cloudrun ? I get 1 or 2 small downtimes periods daily for each apps I run on there (am running some external uptime tool)

Comment: My site is behind a Load Balancer, CDN, Autoscaling, etc. except for the past two days while some site work is being done. I get so much traffic that I need big VM instances, Cloud SQL, etc.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to put the content of your credential JSON (base64 encoded) into an ENV variable on the server configuration interface, and then we you are starting the server manifest the file from the ENV variable.

E.g.: `echo $CREDENTIALS | base64 -d > /path/to/cred.json`, 
then 
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="*file_json_path"`

Comment: But doesn't the cred.json file still need to exist in an insecure location? Isn't that the same problem? As mentioned above, this is a shared virtual host.

Comment: The other processes shouldn't be able to read your resources at all. Ideally your env manifests in a docker or some other fully separated environment. Also, only you and the other person who has permission should be able to read your environment settings as well, so that is secure as well. (eg heroku)

Comment: This method is not recommended for Cloud Run (see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity?hl=en#per-service-identity).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit .bashrc file: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="*file_json_path"
then use: source .bashrc

-- linux mint 19

Answer (score 0):

You can use "gcloud auth application-default login" from your terminal to get authenticated using end-user credentials.

Once you are authenticated, you can use default service objects of any GCP resource.

Comment: Using this method will cause warning messages to be printed from the libraries. Do not use this method except for local testing.

Comment: You can store your credentials in config map file or in kms as well.

Comment: KMS requires credentials to access your encrypted credentials.